# Printing a formatted dictionary key

Tags: python

Basically I want to print a value in a dictionary based on a separate variable.
For example:

```
d={"key1":5, "key2":5}  
x=2  
print("The value is {%d}".format(d["key{%d}".format(x)]))
```

I would like this to output "The value is 5", but it tells me that %d is not part of the key. Is there
any way to make it print what I want it to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the format strings. You are mixing the old-style `%` format strings with the new `str.format` method. Use correct format strings and it will work:

```
>>> print("The value is {}".format(d["key{}".format(x)]))
The value is 5
```

or with old-style formatting:

```
>>> print("The value is %d" % d["key%d" % x])
The value is 5
```